# carregar múltiplos modelos em um controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In my Create function, from my products controller. I make several calls to other models that are used to mount combos on the view blade.

```php
    $grade = Grade::all();
    $marca = Marca::all();
    $ncm = Ncm::all();
    $clafiscal = Clafiscal::all();
    $Otributaria = Origemtributaria::all();
    $unidade = Unidade::all();
...

    return view('products.create',
            compact(
                'page',
                'etiqueta',
                'compCusto',
                'grade',
                'marca',
                'ncm' ,
                'clafiscal',
                'Otributaria',
                'grupo',
                'colecao'...);

Is it possible for me to reduce these calls?
```

Comment: English only on Stackoverflow please.

Comment: Hello Alesson, this is the english site of StackOverflow. To Q&A in portuguese, use this other one: http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question belongs to another Stack Exchange site: http://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Sorry guys! I'm noob here, and i will not do it again. Thank's for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no other way to compact multiple values.

But, if your problem is related to the dirty controller (with many function calls and responsibilities), you should try to create a more specific method, with will handle this dependencies load and dependencies compact.

Try something like this:

```
public function loadDependencies()
{
    $dependencias = [];

    $dependencias['grade'] = Grade::all();
    $dependencias['marca'] = Marca::all();
    $dependencias['ncm'] = Ncm::all();
    $dependencias['clafiscal'] = Clafiscal::all();
    $dependencias['Otributaria'] = Origemtributaria::all();
    $dependencias['unidade'] = Unidade::all();

    return compact($dependencias);
}

public function create()
{
    return view('products.create', $this->loadDependencies());
}
```

Comment: I think the downvote is because this is the english site of StackOverflow. To Q&A in portuguese, use this other site: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: You're possibly right. I wrote an English version, just be to sure.

Comment: Tk @MarlonFerreira